# How to show message to user when new tab is opened

Tags: jquery, html, browser, dom-events

The code below uses `onbeforeunload` to display a message before the user leaves the site.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    //  Was the <a> tag clicked?
    if(isClicked)
    {
        //  Reset isClicked
        isClicked = false;
        //  Display the message
        return 'You are leaving the site.';
    }
});

//  Define a clicked state variable with a default value;
isClicked = false;

$(window).load(function(){
    //  Get all tags with the specified className
    var anchors = $('.leaveSite');

    //  Add the "onclick" listener to each one of them
    anchors.each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function(){
            isClicked = true;
        });
    });
});
```

I thought that **onbeforeunload** worked when new windows/tabs were opened.
How do I make the same happen when a user clicks on a `<a class="leaveSite">` that opens a **new window/tab**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a message, should you write the onbeforeunload function like this

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    //  Was the <a> tag clicked?
    if(isClicked)
    {
        //  Reset isClicked
        isClicked = false;
        //  Display the message
        alert 'You are leaving the site.';
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on what I want to do. For my needs returning a string on `onbeforeunload` will cause the browser to pop up a message with the string I provided and the option to leave the site or stay and cancel the redirect. It is a neat feature I learned on other posts here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If any other answer is better that this, I'd be happy to accept it.

After some testing, I concluded I can't have an **onbeforeunload** event be triggered when the link opens a new window/tab. It is so simply because the **window** object is never told to **unload** in those situations (since the new page will load somewhere else), therefore `onbeforeunload` never triggers.

Perhaps it would be nice to have a new event that triggers when the current page opens a new browser window or tab in the future.

For this case, it is better to add an `onclick="myAlert();"` attribute to the HTML tag and have the function do something like this:

```
function myAlert() {
    alert("A new window/tab is about to be opened.");
}
```